# Testing package's classes with JUnit

Tags: android, junit, sqlite

I'm developing an Android application.

I have a package to access SQLite3. It isn't a ContentProvider. How can I test the package's classes using JUnit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [fairly extensive set of documentation online](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/testing_android.html) for the Android test framework. In addition to testing your activities and such using dedicated test classes, you are also welcome to have simple `TestCase` classes that exercise other classes in your Android app.